# '(Int, Int)' is not identical to 'CGPoint'

Tags: swift

I got error: `'(Int, Int)' is not identical to 'CGPoint'`

How to convert a (Int, Int) to CGPoint

```
let zigzag = [(100,100),
    (100,150),(150,150),
    (150,200)]

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    // Get the drawing context.
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Create the shape (a vertical line) in the context.
    CGContextBeginPath(context)

    //Error is here
    CGContextAddLines(context, zigzag, zigzag.count)

    // Configure the drawing environment.
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,UIColor.redColor().CGColor)

    // Request the system to draw.
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
}
```

Comment: CGPointMake(100, 100)

Comment: Using CGPointMake works, but i want to use (Int, Int)..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate way to avoid the boilerplate code required to create instances of the same type is to make `CGPoint` implement the `ArrayLiteralConvertible`, making it initializable by assigning an array of `CGFloat`:

```
extension CGPoint : ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    public init(arrayLiteral elements: CGFloat...) {
        self.x = elements.count > 0 ? elements[0] : 0.0
        self.y = elements.count > 1 ? elements[1] : 0.0
    }
}
```

and then use it as follows:

```
let zigzag:[CGPoint] = [
    [100,100],
    [100,150],
    [150,150],
    [150,200]
]
```

A few notes:

- stylistically, it doesn't look good - it would be good if literals could be used for tuples, but I am not aware of any way to do that
- if an empty array is used, the `CGPoint` is initialized with `x = 0` and `y = 0`
- if an array with one element is used, it is initialized with `y = 0`
- if more than 2 values are used, all the ones after the 2nd are ignored

Comment: @lijinma thanks :). Also big thank to @MartinR for fixing an error in my code (line `self.y = elements.count > 1 ...`)

Answer (score 3):

`CGContextAddLines()` expects an array of `CGPoint`. If you already have an
array of `(Int, Int)` tuples then you can convert it with

```
let points = zigzag.map { CGPoint(x: $0.0, y: $0.1) }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it tells you to use CGPoint, use it! Just (number,number) is a pair of `int`s.

```
let zigzag = [CGPointMake(100,100),
    CGPointMake(100,150),CGPointMake(150,150),
    CGPointMake(150,200)]
```

Comment: (Or `CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)`)

Comment: Also `zigzag.count` is `Int`, whereas the function requires a `UInt`, so that must be explicitly converted: `UInt(zigzag.count)`

Comment: is it possible to convert (Int, Int) to CGPoint?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another:

```
func CGPoints(points:(x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat)...) -> [CGPoint] {
    return map(points) { CGPoint($0) }
}

let zigzag = CGPoints(
    (100,100),(100,150),(150,150),(150,200)
)
```